# Print Longitude and Latitude in textbox Android

Tags: android, location, latitude-longitude

I have looked about and cannot find any direct threads regarding what I am looking for. I am trying to create an Android application which dials out an emergency number at the push of a button (which I have got working) but cannot get the location (displayed in Longitude and Latitude) to display, I have tried doing it with Toast and EditText boxes. I am new to Android development so wanted to start with something easy, but the LongLat part is being troublesome. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code I have been tampering with in order to try and get it to grab the Long and Lat, then in another file I have been trying to use a click listener to assign it to a button so when the button is pressed (in main.xml) it will display the Long and Lat either in a textfield or in toast.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.Criteria;



        public class EmergencyLocation extends Activity implements LocationListener {
            private TextView latituteField;
            private TextView longitudeField;
            private LocationManager locationManager;
            private String provider;

            /** Called when the activity is first created. **/
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
                longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.long_lat);

                // Get the location manager
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                // Define the criteria how to select the location provider -> use
                // default
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                // Initialise the location fields
                if (location != null) {
                    System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
                    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
                    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
                    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
                    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
                } else {
                    latituteField.setText("Provider not available");
                    longitudeField.setText("Provider not available");
                }
            }








        private void TextView() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }}
```

Comment: post your code...that will be helpful to understand...

Comment: That was the code I was given and have tried to adapt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to set up a `LocationManager`:

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// set preferred provider based on the best accuracy possible
Criteria fineAccuracyCriteria = new Criteria();
fineAccuracyCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
String preferredProvider = manager.getBestProvider(fineAccuracyCriteria, true);
```

Now, you have to create a `LocationListener`. In this case, it calls the method `updateLocation()`:

```
LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
            updateLocation(location);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };
```

**EDIT:**

Then, you have to register the listener with your `LocationManager` (and try to get the cached location):

```
manager.requestLocationUpdates(preferredProvider, 0, 0, listener);
// get a fast fix - cached version
updateLocation(manager.getLastKnownLocation());
```

And finally, the `updateLocation()` method:

```
private void updateLocation(Location location) {
    if (location == null)
        return;

    // save location details
    latitude = (float) location.getLatitude();
    longitude = (float) location.getLongitude();        
}
```

**EDIT2:**

OK, just saw your code. In order to make it work, just move around a few bits:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. **/
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.long_lat);

    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the location provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    onLocationChanged(location);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   if (location != null) {
       System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
       int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
       int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
       latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
       longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
   } else {
       latituteField.setText("Provider not available");
       longitudeField.setText("Provider not available");
   }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is that all in one class file? For example I have a file called EmergencyLocation.java is that all within that one? I tried creating two files earlier, one with the LocationListiner and the other with a onClick so I could get it to display at the touch of the button but it wouldn't work.

Comment: If that's the only place where you will use the LocationManager in the application, it will do it well. If you plan in reusing it, your best bet is to use a separate class (or an Application object) to manage your LocationManager and register listeners and unregister as you need them. From within updateLocation(), provided it's in the same class as your UI, you can update the information you want. Bear in mind, though, that you might click the button before you actually  received any information from the LocationManager. In that case, refer to my edited post.

Comment: Yes, I only plan on using LocationListener once, and in one file. So the Long and Lat can be displayed at the users discretion, I'm just having trouble getting it to display, it maybe that the code I have tried isn't working so there's nothing to display!

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help, I just seem to be making a bigger and bigger hash of this. I was instructed that this is a simple-ish project to do, not finding it that way! Chopping and changing my code and I think I may have deleted key bits. Eclipse offering suggestions I don't understand aha.

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy. I use the *locationListener* as an attribute inside a *Location* class. Here's how I do it:

```
package com.rifsoft.android.helper.location;

import com.rifsoft.android.helper.IListener;

import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Location implements IListener
{
  public final static int IDX_LATITIDE = 0;
  public final static int IDX_LONGITUDE = 1;

  private double[] lastLocation =  {0.0, 0.0};  
  private LocationManager locationManager = null;
  private ILocation activity = null;

  private LocationListener locationListener  = new LocationListener()
  {
      public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) 
      {
        // TODO: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#BestEstimate
        lastLocation[IDX_LATITIDE] = location.getLatitude();
        lastLocation[IDX_LONGITUDE] = location.getLongitude();
        activity.onLocationChange();
      }

      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

  /**
   * Constructor, needs LocationManager
   * @param activity Activity that will receive the notification when location has changed
   * @param locationManager LocationManager
   */
  public Location(final ILocation act, LocationManager lm) throws LocationException
  {
    if (lm == null)
    {
      throw new LocationException(LocationException.ERR_NULL_LOCATION_MANAGER);
    }

    if (act == null)
    {
      throw new LocationException(LocationException.ERR_NULL_ILOCATION);
    }

    locationManager = lm;
    activity = act;

    registerListener();   

    android.location.Location lastCachedLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (lastCachedLocation != null)
    {
      lastLocation[IDX_LATITIDE] = lastCachedLocation.getLatitude();
      lastLocation[IDX_LONGITUDE] = lastCachedLocation.getLatitude();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Retuns last known most accurate location as latitude, longitude
   * @return Latitude, Longitude
   */
  public double[] getLastLocation()
  {
    return lastLocation;
  }

  @Override
  public void registerListener() 
  {   
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);   
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);   
  }

  @Override
  public void unRegisterListener() 
  {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);    
  }
}
```

Then the activity.onLocationChange() goes like

```
  public void onLocationChange() 
  {
    locationUpdated = true;

    double[] coordinates = location.getLastLocation();

    EditText lon = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.longitude_value);
    lon.setText(String.valueOf(coordinates[Location.IDX_LONGITUDE]));

    EditText lat = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.latitude_value);   
    lat.setText(String.valueOf(coordinates[Location.IDX_LATITIDE]));
  }
```

Comment: I personally have blocked EditTexts for immediate visual debugging. I edited my answer. I see you're talking about "all in one class" below. It doesn't have to be like that. It depends on how you organize and design your code. I presonally prefer breaking big classes into smaller ones. Also using interfaces is recommended. Last but not least, I suggest you read Android documentation before trying to program for Android.

Comment: lastLocation[IDX_LATITIDE] = location.getLatitude();
      lastLocation[IDX_LONGITUDE] = location.getLongitude();
      activity.onLocationChange();

The locations cannot be resolved to a variable, any idea why?
Why block EditTexts? I have been reading from Beginning ANdroid, but couldn't find anything on this subject, reading lots of text on screen hazes my eyes.

Comment: My apologies, there's a storm and the power went down for ten seconds, apparently it sent some of what I was saying.

Comment: Oh ok, no problem. I guess you mean *lastLocation* cannot be resolved? Because *location* is passed as argument... This is because this is another attribute on my class. I'll post the whole class so you can see how I'm doing it. I use this Location class as a generic helper, so I can reuse this very same class on any other project. Keep in mind I won't post any copy-paste code, since I don't have time and it's not my style. I prefer you to understand how to do it instead of copy-pasting it.

Comment: That's brilliant, no I don't want copy&paste as such, I want to know what is going on! I get told one thing by the book, another by the internet. Changed my code so much now it's ridiculous! Got several tabs open with different bits of code to see which (if any) I can get working first. I really appreciate you taking the time to assist. Thank you.