# Pass Latitude and Longitude to Google API Places Search in Android

Tags: java, android, google-api

I have literally been searching for this for weeks. I am a novice java programmer but I have been able to piece together an app that can use a double latitude and longitude hard coded in the same class. It will show a list of current places surrounding those points. I have another separate class with a method that is able to get the current location based on the gps/network but I can't pass the variables created from this second class to the PlaceRequest class. I have looked through all of the tutorials on the above subjects but there isn't anything combining current location and place search results. I have two getters declared but can't call the variables in these. Again sort of a rookie so may be an easy fix. Any ideas?

Update - Here is my code so far:
GooglePlaceActivity.java

```
    public class GooglePlaceActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button btn1;
TextView txt1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(l);     
}

private class SearchSrv extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, PlacesList>{

    @Override
    protected PlacesList doInBackground(Void... params) {

        PlacesList pl = null;
        try {
            pl = new PlaceRequest().performSearch();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pl;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(PlacesList result) {

        String text = "Result \n";

        if (result!=null){
            for(Place place: result.results){
                text = text + place.name +"\n";
            }
            txt1.setText(text);
        }
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }
}

View.OnClickListener l = new View.OnClickListener() {   

    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SearchSrv srv = new SearchSrv();
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        srv.execute();          

    }
};
```

}

//////////////////////

PlaceRequest.java

```
    public class PlaceRequest {

private static final HttpTransport transport = new ApacheHttpTransport();

private static final String API_KEY = "keyhere";
private static final String LOG_KEY = "GGPlace";
// The different Places API endpoints.
private static final String PLACES_SEARCH_URL =  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
private static final String PLACES_AUTOCOMPLETE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?";
private static final String PLACES_DETAILS_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?";

private static final boolean PRINT_AS_STRING = true;


//double latitude;
//double longitude;

CurrentLocation clo = new CurrentLocation(null);
//clo.onLocationChanged(latitude);
//double longitude = CurrentLocation.getLongitude();
//double latitude = CurrentLocation.getLatitude();
double longi = clo.getLongitude();
double lat = clo.getLatitude();

public PlacesList performSearch() throws Exception {

    try {
        //CurrentLocation currlo = new CurrentLocation();
        //double lat = currlo.getLatitude();
        //double longi = currlo.getLongitude();
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, "Start Search");
        GenericUrl reqUrl = new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL);
        reqUrl.put("key", API_KEY);
        //reqUrl.put("location", latitude + "," + longitude);
        //reqUrl.put("location", getLatitude(latitude) + "," + getLongitude());
        reqUrl.put("location", lat + "," + longi);
        reqUrl.put("radius", 1600);
        reqUrl.put("types", "food");
        reqUrl.put("sensor", "false");
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, "url= " + reqUrl);
        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(transport);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory.buildGetRequest(reqUrl);

            Log.v(LOG_KEY, request.execute().parseAsString());                          
            PlacesList places = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
            Log.v(LOG_KEY, "STATUS = " + places.status);
            for (Place place : places.results) {
                Log.v(LOG_KEY, place.name);             

            }
            return places;

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, e.getResponse().parseAsString());
        throw e;
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        throw e;
    }
}

public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(final HttpTransport transport) {

      return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
       public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
        GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
        headers.setApplicationName("Google-Places-DemoApp");
        request.setHeaders(headers);
        JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory()) ;
        //JsonHttpParser.builder(new JacksonFactory());
        //parser.jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        request.addParser(parser);
       }
    });
}
```

}

/////////////
CurrentLocation.java

```
    public class CurrentLocation {

    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

    LocationManager locationManager ;
    double latitude=0;
    double longitude=0;


    public CurrentLocation(Context ctxt) {
super();
locationManager = (LocationManager) ctxt.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
        MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
        MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, 
        new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getLatitude();

            }
        });

    }
    public double getLatitude() {
return latitude;
    }
    public double getLongitude() {
return longitude;
    } 
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't pass the variables created from this second class to the PlaceRequest class"?  I don't think anyone's going to be able to help you without more details - perhaps some code?  Also, please explain _exactly_ where you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marvin. Basically I have 2 classes. the CurrentLocation.java file gets the current location and uses two getters: public double getLatitude() {
 //latitude = 40.77203;
 return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
 //longitude = -96.61344;
 return longitude;
}

Comment: The other class is PlaceRequest.java which performs a place search based on hard coded latitude and longitude variables but I want to use the variables from the CurrentLocation.java files which are dynamic based on location. I have tried a variety of different solutions with no luck. Here is a some of the code: CurrentLocation clo = new CurrentLocation(null);
 
 double longi = clo.getLongitude();
    double lat = clo.getLatitude();

Comment: I think the solution may be something simple but I'm still learning the basic of java - thanks for any suggestions. I'd be happy to email my code too.

Comment: Please edit your post and include both `CurrentLocation.java` and `PlaceRequest.java`. Also include the main activity that calls on `CurrentLocation` and/or `PlaceRequest` (if appropriate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: After looking your complete code, I see a few fundamental design flaws so I'm going to show you how I did it and you can adapt it to your program flow.  Please keep in mind that this example is *vastly* simplified from my original, but it should be enough to get you going.

First, the `CurrentLocation.java` file.  My design decision for wrapping this in a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) was so that I can re-use it in multiple activities with the added bonus of *killing* it when necessary.

```
public class CurrentLocation implements Callable<Location> {

  private static final String TAG = "CurrentLocation";
  private Context context;
  private LocationManager lm;
  private Criteria criteria;
  private Location bestResult;
  private boolean locationListenerWorking;


  public CurrentLocation(Context context) {
    lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
    criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    bestResult = null;
    locationListenerWorking = false;
  }


  public Location call() {
    return getLoc();
  }


  private Location getLoc() {
    String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if (provider != null) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Using provider: " +provider);
      locationListenerWorking = true;
      lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                                0,
                                0,
                                singeUpdateListener,
                                context.getMainLooper());
    } else {
      Log.w(TAG, "Couldn't find a location provider");
      return null;
    }



    while (locationListenerWorking) {
      // Check for the interrupt signal - terminate if necessary
      if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "User initiated interrupt (cancel signal)");
        cleanup();
        break;
      }

      try {
        // ghetto implementation of a busy wait...
        Thread.sleep(500); // Sleep for half a second
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Thread interrupted..");
        cleanup();
        break;
      }
    }

    return bestResult;
  }




  private void cleanup() {
    if (lm != null) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Location manager not null - cleaning up");
      lm.removeUpdates(singeUpdateListener);
    } else {
      Log.d(TAG, "Location manager was NULL - no cleanup necessary");
    }
  }




  /**
   * This one-off {@link LocationListener} simply listens for a single location
   * update before unregistering itself.  The one-off location update is
   * returned via the {@link LocationListener} specified in {@link
   * setChangedLocationListener}.
   */
  private LocationListener singeUpdateListener = new LocationListener() {
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got a location update");
        if (location == null) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Seems as if we got a null location");
        } else {
          bestResult = location;
        }

        cleanup();
        locationListenerWorking = false;
      }

      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}    
      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };

}
```

Then in your *calling* class (i.e. where you need the lat/lon coordinates - you want to do this from an `Activity`):

```
private class GetLocationTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Location> {
  private Future<Location> future;
  private ExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);
  private boolean cancelTriggered = false;

  protected void onPreExecute() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting location get...");
  }

  public Location doInBackground(Void... arg) {
    CurrentLocation currLoc = new CurrentLocation(getApplicationContext());
    future = executor.submit(currLoc);
    long LOCATION_TIMEOUT = 20000; // ms = 20 sec
    try {
      // return future.get(Constants.LOCATION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      return future.get(LOCATION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Location get timed out");
      future.cancel(true);
      return null;
    }
  }

  public boolean killTask() {
    cancelTriggered = true;
    boolean futureCancelRes = future.cancel(true);
    this.cancel(true);
    Log.d(TAG, "Result of cancelling task: " +futureCancelRes);
    return futureCancelRes;
  }


  protected void onPostExecute(Location res) {
    if (cancelTriggered) {
      Log.d(TAG, "User initiated cancel - this is okay");
      cancelTriggered = false;
    } else if (res == null) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Could not get a location result");
    } else {
      double lat = res.getLatitude();
      double lon = res.getLongitude();
      Log.d(TAG, "Latitude: " +lat);
      Log.d(TAG, "Longitude: " +lon);
    }
  }
}
```

Finally to wrap things up, here's how you call it:

```
GetLocationTask t = new GetLocationTask();
t.execute();
```

And if you need to kill the location update for whatever reason (if your user switches out of your activity, etc), this will kill the `AsyncTask` as well as the associated Future task.

```
t.killTask();
```

P.S. You may want to get your API keys changed and edit it out of your post.

Comment: Thanks Marvin!  I really appreciate your help and apologize for not providing enough info. I posted my code above if that helps :) The above doesn't have any errors in eclipse but when I run in the emulator and feed it gps coordinates via ddms it displays nothing. I tried hardcoding the lat and lon in the getters but still didn't work. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Right off the bat, I see that you're calling `CurrentLocation(Context ctxt)` with `null`. How did you expect it to retrieve the `locationManager` object from that? Also, keep in mind that `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates` is an asynchronous process so you cannot expect to receive the lat and lon immediately after that. `clo.getLongitude()` will almost always return their default values (in this case `0`). The `onLocationChanged` callback was designed for this.

Comment: Ha - and here lies my real problem - I'm a rookie at this. I recieved errors when trying to call CurrentLocation() with no arguments so this was my best guess. I tried all sorts of things but nothing worked. Do you know what this argument needs to be? Just trying to ultimately learn java and in the process android but I can imagine my code is a mess...

Comment: Marvin I can't thank you enough!  I'm a designer with php skills but really want to learn java. I'm excited to learn what/why you changed what you did. Now how do I buy you a beer!!!

Comment: @mikeinlincoln You're welcome :) Since you're just starting out, work on getting the user's location (consistently) and then move on to the `Places` API.  Build out from the location example.

Comment: Sounds good, Thanks Marvin - I really appreciate it! Just trying to digest it all :)