# How to get current lattitude and longitude and passed to an google places api in html

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I get the Google Places API code and I have also added my code to it,
I have already got a current position like latitude and longitude but I don't know how to pass variable like lat1 and lng1 to Google API.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Place searches</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function initGeolocation()
     {
        if( navigator.geolocation )
        {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( success, fail );
        }
        else
        {
           alert("Sorry, your browser does not support geolocation services.");
        }
     }

     function success(position)
     {

         var lng1= position.coords.longitude;
         var lat1= position.coords.latitude;
     }


      function fail()
      {
        // Could not obtain location
      }

    </script>  
    <script>


      var map;

      var infowindow;

      function initMap() {
        var pyrmont = {lat:lat1, lng:lng1};

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: pyrmont,
          zoom: 15
        });

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch({
          location: pyrmont,
          radius: 500,
          type: ['store']
        }, callback);
      }

      function callback(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
          }
        }
      }

      function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="initGeolocation();">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDFvTqvbyut42xc-nF2kToD0Mzwh-_nVvw&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have already declared variables also but when I pass it shows nothing...
Advance Thanks!!!
If anyone knows how to pass the current latitude and longitude variables to google API code leave an answer here!

Comment: i have already calculate the latitude and longitude but how to pass that both value to google places api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

  <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>



<script>
 var x = document.getElementById("demo");

   function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
} else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
 }
}

    function showPosition(position) {
x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
 }

   function showError(error) {
switch(error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
        break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
        break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
        x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
        break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
        break;
  }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48353881/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: i have already calculate the latitude and longitude but how to pass that both value to google places api

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719779/pass-latitude-and-longitude-to-google-api-places-search-in-android     Check this link

Comment: but i want in html not in java

Comment: This is not accurate. If you get the lat long trough the geolocation and then you pass lat long obtained to google maps api you will get a non accurate address